# How to find running time of recursive binary search?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, procedure

For each of the procedures below, let T (n) be the running time. Find the order of T (n) (i.e., find f(n) such that T (n) ∈ (f(n)).

```
Procedure BinarySearch(table T [a . . . b], int k):
 if a > b then
  return -1
 end if
 middle ← ⌊(a + b)/2⌋
 if T [middle] = k then
  return middle
 end if
 if k < T [middle] then
  return BinarySearch(T [a . . .middle], k)
 else
  return BinarySearch(T [middle . . . b], k)
 end if
```

I know how to find run times of simple functions but since this includes recursive calls so I'm having trouble.

Comment: if you think about it a little bit, then you can intuitively deduce that it's `O(log2(n))`.

Comment: Lets say you have T( n ). Well for each T ( n ) , you split it in half. so T ( n / 2 ). How many times can you split n in half? see @H2CO3 's comment.

Comment: You have a bug in your pseudocode. Let a=1 and b=2, and T[2]=k. Then middle=(a+b)/2=1 and k > T[1]. You will recursively call BinarySearch(T [1 ... 2], k). You should better change your pseudocode to "return BinarySearch(T [a . . .middle-1], k)" and "return BinarySearch(T [middle+1 . . . b], k)". As you have already checked T[middle], there is no sense in checking it again.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) (bottom of the page) depicts a very clear way of solving the recurrence relation of Binary Search algorithm.